# nuxt js delete action in the vuex

Tags: api, vue.js, axios, nuxt.js, vuex

I have a nuxt job page where I call all the jobs from an api.
Now I want to delete a job using axios and it is deleted on client side but when I do refresh the page, all the deleted items are coming back.

Those are my action and mutation:

```js
//action
async effacerJobApi({ commit }, offre) {
  axios.delete(`/offres/${offre.id}`)
  commit('EFFACER_JOB', offre.id);
},

//mutation
EFFACER_JOB(state, offreId) {
  let offres = state.offres.filter(v=> v.id != offreId);
  state.offres = offres;
},
```

Comment: First: Start using [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await). Second: evaluate if response is actually sucessfull and only remove Item from local data if it has been deleted, otherwise show error. 
If it actually has been deleted from the Server and still exists in your frontend it's most likely that you have some sort of persistence (localStorage, Cookies etc) which cached your data.

Comment: As said above, if it's not deleted on the backend, you'll download it again on the client once refreshed. Be sure that it is removed from the backend. And please also provide us more details as of what is happening with your state here (how you're fetching it from the backend). Lastly (style tip), try to write your codebase in english, it's more universal than french.